# Using a Case Statement in a Function

Tags: sql, db2

I am having issues with a piece of a query I am writing- I'm creating an indicator field that I only want to show up as '1' if a couple of cases are satisfied. The field is built using a case statement inside a MAX() function- I need the function because this portion is part of a CTE that is joined with another CTE that is turning rows into columns and I used functions to lateralize.

```
 MAX(CASE
     WHEN PMOD1_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD1_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     WHEN PMOD2_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD2_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     WHEN PMOD3_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD3_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     WHEN PMOD4_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD4_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     WHEN PMOD5_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD5_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     WHEN PMOD6_PGM IN ('IR') AND INTEGER(PMOD6_PCT) <> 0
       THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END) AS @IRPM_IND,
      /*@IRPM_PCT*/
 MAX(CASE
     WHEN PMOD1_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD1_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD1_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('D')
       THEN PMOD1_PCT
     WHEN PMOD2_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD2_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD2_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('D')
       THEN PMOD2_PCT
     WHEN PMOD3_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD3_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD3_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('D')
       THEN PMOD3_PCT
     WHEN PMOD4_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD4_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD4_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('D')
       THEN PMOD4_PCT
     WHEN PMOD5_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD5_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD5_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('D')
       THEN PMOD5_PCT
     WHEN PMOD6_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD6_PCT * - 1
     WHEN PMOD6_PGM IN ('IR') AND PMOD1_CD IN ('C')
       THEN PMOD6_PCT
     ELSE 0 END) AS @IRPM_PCT
```

Basically I check one field to see if 'IR' is present and that its percent is not equal to 0- if so I want an indicator of 1. But when I run this, there are still some entries coming through with an indicator of 1 and a @IRPM_PCT of 0. Any advice? Does it have to do with the case statements being in a MAX() function? When I check the data that comes through, it seems to "work" but I would like to eliminate these indicator of 1, percent of 0 cases and I thought the way I built the Indicator case statement would deal with this.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Could you share some sample data, the result you're trying to get, and the result you're actually getting?

Comment: The PMOD#_PGM fields are 2 CHAR and denote a certain program being used. In the example, I want to find 'IR' and build an indicator that it is present. However, the PMOD#_PCT fields are a DECIMAL that gives a percentage being applied in the corresponding PGM. So in the first block, I first want to check if 'IR' is present and that its PCT is not equal to 0- if so I want an indicator of 1. That's the result I'm trying to get.

Comment: What I'm still getting is a few rows with an IRPM_IND of 1 and an IRPM_PCT of 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the IRPM_PCT CASE statement, you check PMOD6_PGM for 'C' twice (instead of for 'C' and then for 'D').

So if PMOD6_PGM = 'IR', PMOD6_PCT is non-zero, and PMOD1_CD = 'D',
then you'll get IRPM_IND = 1 and IRPM_PCT = 0 (because `PMOD1_CD IN ('D')` is not in the IRPM_PCT CASE statement).

So just change your last `PMOD1_CD IN ('C')` to `PMOD1_CD IN ('D')`.

Comment: Also, all of your PMOD#_CD checks are for PMOD1_CD.  Is that the way it's supposed to be?  or should they be PMOD1_CD, PMOD2_CD, PMOD3_CD, etc.?